# Adonis: How to add an index to a column that already exists?

Tags: adonis.js

I have some existing columns in my table that I want to add an index on. How can I proceed? From the documentation it says:

> table..index([indexName], [indexType]) // Specifies column as an index.

But what does indexName mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have head over to the [Knex.js documentation](http://knexjs.org/#Schema-index).

> **index** — table.index(columns, [indexName], [indexType])
>
> Adds an index to a table over the given columns. A default index name using the columns is used
> unless indexName is specified. The indexType can be optionally specified for PostgreSQL and
> MySQL. Amazon Redshift does not allow creating an index.

Here is how I did it:

```js
/**************************************************************************
 * IMPORTS
 ***************************************************************************/

// Providers
const Schema = use('Schema')

/**************************************************************************
 * MIGRATIONS
 ***************************************************************************/

class AddDomainsIndexSchema extends Schema {
  up() {
    this.table('domains', (table) => {
      table.index('domain')
      table.index('fetched')
    })
  }

  down() {
    this.table('domains', (table) => {
      table.dropIndex('domain')
      table.dropIndex('fetched')
    })
  }
}

module.exports = AddDomainsIndexSchema
```